# Script gets data perfectly in browser, but doesn't when run using cmd

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, web-scraping

I'm trying to get data by targeting `id` of elements form a webpage by using DOMParser, and storing this data in a MySQL database.

When I do this in a browser using a function to be executed on button click, I get the data perfectly, which is then added to a table on the webpage.

But, when I create a similar script which has an additional function to add this data to a MySQL database, it doesn't get the required data, but returns undefined. I think this is something related to synchronous and asynchronous requests, but it was working perfectly in the browser!

**Script for HTML page run in a browser(Google Chrome)**

```
var data1, data2, data3, data4;
var sno = 1;

function go(){
var iurl = 'http://example.com';
$.get(iurl, function(response){
    let parser = new DOMParser();
    let parsedHtml = parser.parseFromString(response, 'text/html');
    data1 = parsedHtml.getElementById('data1id').value;
    data2 = parsedHtml.getElementById('data2id').value;
    data3 = parsedHtml.getElementById('data3id').value;
    data4 = parsedHtml.getElementById('data4id').value;
    $(".table-main").append("\<tr\>\<td\>" + sno + "\<\/td\>\<td\>" + data1 + "\<\/td\>\<td\>" + data2 + "\<\/td\>\<td\>" + data3 + "\<\/td\>\<td\>" + data4 + "\<\/td\>\<\/tr\>");
    sno++;
    second();
})}

function second(){
    console.log("INSERT into AllTheData values ('" + sno + "', '" + data1 + "', '"  + data2 + "', '" + data3 + "', '" + data4 +"')");
// returns the required data
}
```

**Script to be run using cmd (and Node.js)**

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
var { JSDOM } = jsdom;
var { window } = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html>`);
var $ = require('jquery')(window);
var DomParser = require('dom-parser');
var parser = new DomParser();

var data1, data2, data3, data4;
var sno = 1;
function go(){
var iurl = 'http://example.com';
$.get(iurl, function(response){
    let parsedHtml = parser.parseFromString(response, 'text/html');
    data1 = parsedHtml.getElementById('data1id').value;
    data2 = parsedHtml.getElementById('data2id').value;
    data3 = parsedHtml.getElementById('data3id').value;
    data4 = parsedHtml.getElementById('data4id').value;
    sno++;
second()
})}

function second(){ // Doesn't return the required data
console.log("INSERT into AllTheData values ('" + sno + "', '" + data1 + "', '"  + data2 + "', '" + data3 + "', '" + data4 +"')");
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({host : "localhost", user: "root", password: <password>, database : <database name> , insecureAuth: true});

 con.connect(function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
    var sql = "INSERT into <table name> values ('" + sno + "', '" + data1 + "', '"  + data2 + "', '" + data3 + "', '" + data4 +"')";
    con.query(sql, function(err, result){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("1 record inserted!");
    });
});}
```

I run the script from cmd by navigating to its location using `cd`, and then

```
node <filename>
```

It returns (where `1` is the value in `sno`)

```
INSERT into <table name> values (1, 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined')
Connected!
1 record inserted!
```

and the values `undefined` are inserted in the MySQL table.

Expected:

```
INSERT into <table name> values (1, <value of data1>, <value of data2>, <value of data3>, <value of data4>)
Connected!
1 record inserted!
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with CMD. You have **NO** batchfile in your question.

Comment: @Noodles Yeah thanks. I've removed the `cmd` tag.

Comment: You don't seem to be calling the function `second`

Comment: @jro I missed it in the question, but it was there in the file. Thanks for pointing it out. I've edited the question.

Comment: The docs from `dom-parser` example shows second param as encoding format, in example `utf8`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @naga-elixir-jar. That was indeed the issue I had ignored!